# How to secure Django Tastypie REST API which needs no credentails for POST and GET

Tags: python, django, rest, https, django-rest-framework

Hi am having an API url when a user submits the page, URL will be called and POSTED data will be saved in DB through tastypie api.

My question here is,

Am not using credentials while POSting data since it is a form submission, so when an intruder comes to know about my API url and data to be posted he can post bulk amount of data to my DB and crash it,right?

How to prevent this or it is already prevented by any measure,Please Explain.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to authenticate the request

Comment: I cant authenticate the POST request since any one coming to my website can submit it with proper data.

Comment: simply, use username and password combination and verify if it at server. unless they know the combination, their POST request can be invalidated at the server side.

Comment: You mean the username and password of users who are submitting the form or something else?

Comment: can you tell me what exactly the app is about? will the API endpoint be used by only you? Or there are users who log in and do POST?

Comment: Sorry Let me make it clear, am having a form in my webpage and whenever an anonymous user comes to the page he can fill the details in form and submits it.When he clicks submit my AJAX script will POST the data to API URL and it will be stored in my DB. Now say some one comes to know about my API URL and data to be posted he can write a script and flood my DB ,how this can be prevented. Thanks.

Comment: @Mithu actually any one can do the same writing a simple script with curl to post data an flood your db. If you want to securize your url you must use an auth mechanism.

Comment: actually I found a way, refer here - http://codrspace.com/vote539/csrf-protection-in-django-tastypie/

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with tastypie but they have an [authentication and authorization section in their docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to allow people to POST with no auth, then there is nothing you can do to prevent someone just POSTing random data. What you can do is throttling the user so they don't post that much data.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/throttling.html

Comment: Not a terrible solution. However, that could really screw up the integrity of your data and a dedicated hacker could just create a new thread for each request and keep changing their IP with a VPN.